# Export to excel not working in safari browser

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core, safari, epplus

I am trying to export Excel in .NET Core using ExcelPackage in "EPPlus.Core.dll". It is working fine in all browsers except Safari.

I have used the below content-type for export.

```
PhysicalFile("Users.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

Is there any way to export Excel in Safari?

Comment: Every browser has in some parts his own special behaviour. As safari is not that popular i suggest you to not waste time for this specific case.